# Library dependency issues with gradle 3.0.0-alphaX

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, jitpack

I have a library project with submodules that include many dependencies that I'd like to pass to the developer's application. For example, module `A` may include all the necessary appcompat dependencies.

With the [migration changes](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html), I've updated all `compile` cases to `api`, which should not affect anything. However, I no longer have access to any of the libraries dependencies. I can only use code and references from my library itself.

Is there any way around this?

One of the build gradle files of my library submodules can be found [here](https://github.com/AllanWang/KAU/blob/canary/core/build.gradle) for reference.

The dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${KOTLIN}"

    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBS}"
    api "com.android.support:support-v13:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBS}"
    api "com.android.support:design:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBS}"
    api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBS}"
    api "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBS}"
    api "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:${CONSTRAINT_LAYOUT}"

    api "com.mikepenz:iconics-core:${ICONICS}@aar"
    api "com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:${IICON_GOOGLE}.original@aar"

    api "com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:${MATERIAL_DIALOG}"

    api "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${TIMBER}"

    api "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:${ANKO}"
}
```

Edit:

To clarify, the sample project in the module actually does build properly, but there's an issue with using the dependencies in any other app, where it pulls from jitpack. See [this gradle](https://github.com/AllanWang/Frost-for-Facebook/blob/canary/app/build.gradle) as an example that won't build.
I've tried using combinations of api, implementation, @aar, and transitive.

Come to think of it, this may be a jitpack issue and not a gradle issue, but if anyone else has a resolution I'd like to hear it.

Comment: I has this issue with bazel. Don't sure how to fix this issue with gradle but you can google it with keywords "transient dependencies". Obviously, the easiest way is to provide all dependencies that your module needs directly in module build.gradle.

Comment: @uselessdinosaur there may be more to it. I've tried transitive dependencies and it didn't seem to work, but upon closer inspections and from the answer below, this may be a jitpack specific issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the android-maven-gradle-plugin

I[ssue Report](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin/issues/61)

Comment: It's has been fixed in version "2.0"

Answer (score 1):

> I no longer have access to any of the libraries dependencies. I can only use code and references from my library itself.

It is correct.

From the [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) :

> ```
> dependencies {
>     api 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
>     implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5' 
> }
> ```
>
> Dependencies appearing in the `api` configurations will be
>   transitively exposed to consumers of the library, and as such will
>   appear on the compile classpath of consumers.
>
> Dependencies found in the `implementation` configuration will, on the
>   other hand, not be exposed to consumers, and therefore not leak into
>   the consumers' compile classpath. This comes with several benefits:
>
> - dependencies do not leak into the compile classpath of consumers anymore, so you will never accidentally depend on a transitive
>     dependency
> - faster compilation thanks to reduced classpath size
> - less recompilations when implementation dependencies change: consumers would not need to be recompiled
> - cleaner publishing: when used in conjunction with the new maven-publish plugin, Java libraries produce POM files that
>     distinguish exactly between what is required to compile against the
>     library and what is required to use the library at runtime (in other
>     words, don't mix what is needed to compile the library itself and what
>     is needed to compile against the library).

---

Comment: This ended up being an issue with the dcendants maven plugin. Having everything with api was a test to see if it would work, and it should have behaved exactly as the old compile option.

Answer (score 0):

It's has been fixed in version "2.0" of [android-maven-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/dcendents/android-maven-gradle-plugin)

just update to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
}
```

or using the new syntax since Gradle 2.1

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.dcendents.android-maven" version "2.0"
}
```

---

---

using `api` in your library module allows you to access the transient dependencies **only** in your library code; not the apps that consume it.

so to achieve the desired effect you need to change in your sample module.

```
implementation project(':core')
```

to

```
api project(':core')
```

---

**note** you don't need to use `api` in your library it's better to use `implementation` as it speeds up your build.

Comment: It actually works with the sample app, but not with other apps which pull from jitpack. Additionally, why should a sample model use `api` rather than `implementation`? It has no need to pass out another interface to another package. I'm considering moving the project dependencies to implementations, but it will mean that those who want to pick one specific project will need to add the other dependencies themselves. But regardless, since `api` isn't working, I'm not at that stage yet.